# Scraping works sometimes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape https://www.trulia.com/sold/32303_zip/6_srl/, I simply need the number of homes sold which is stated in the ...."sold homes on Trulia" sentence at the top right. The code below sometimes gets the number, other times it gets "Nearby" from the "Nearby Real Estate" from the bottom, which is another h2 element. What is wrong or missing from my code?

```
url = "https://www.trulia.com/sold/32303_zip/6_srl/"
html = requests.get(url)
html = html.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.get_text()
s = soup.div.h2.get_text()
s = s.split()
s = s[0]
s = s.replace(',', '')
```

Comment: Have you looked at the page you get back, using `curl` or `wget`?  That page is completely built dynamically using Javascript.  There is essentially no HTML in the data you get back.  BeautifulSoup can't help.  The information you want is in there, embedded in a JSON object.  You may be able to use normal string searches to find it.

Comment: Oh, I did not realize that. Using curl/wget and doing a string search was my next option, but I figured I would ask some experts first. Thank you for responding and the advice, Tim.

Comment: no it's available on the html `<span class="SearchResultsHeadings__CountText-sc-1cad3tj-2 fexrDT">(786 results)</span>`

Comment: @diggusbickus  Thank you! I updated the code with the span tag and class name, but the same thing continues to occur.

Comment: I managed to it working using wget and parsing the content as a string. Both solutions opened my eyes to the actual structure and location of the data I needed to acquire. Thank you both for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use selenium. First:

```
pip install selenium
```

Then [download a webdriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) that matches your [current chrome browser](https://help.zenplanner.com/hc/en-us/articles/204253654-How-to-Find-Your-Internet-Browser-Version-Number-Google-Chrome). After that, add the chromedriver.exe to your working directory and run the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.trulia.com/sold/32303_zip/6_srl/")
try:
    homes_sold = (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='resultsColumn']/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/h2").text).split(' ')[0]
except:
    homes_sold = (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='resultsColumn']/div[1]/div/div[1]/span").text).split(' ')[0]
    homes_sold = homes_sold.replace('(','')
print(homes_sold)
```

Using requests would work as well. I am just providing an alternate example.

Comment: Luke, thanks for response. It seems to be working now using wget and parsing it as a string. Thanks tough, I'm going to save your solution as well as try it the next time I need to do something similar.

Comment: @Krisstian Great news! Glad I could be of some help. I encourage you to experiment with that library.

Comment: I will! Thanks, again, Luke.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using wget and parsing the content as a string as per @Tim Roberts suggestion.

```
filename = wget.download("https://www.trulia.com/sold/32303_zip/6_srl/")
file = open(filename, 'r')
file = str(file.read())
x = file.partition('subHeaderTag":"')
x = x[2]
x = x.split()
x = x[0]
x = x.replace(',', '')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `wget` or `curl`, you can scrape the number for sold houses using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library without the need to use `selenium` as the data you want to extract doesn't render via Javascript. Plus it will be much faster than launching the whole browser.

To get the required data, you need to get a [`.class` selector](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-with-css-selectors-using-python/#class_selector) which is responsible for the desired result. In our case, this is the `.fdsGMZ` selector. Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to easily pick selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser which is not always working perfectly, if the page heavily uses JS (in this case we can).

Also, if you need to extract information about house listings (geolocation, address, price, pictures, etc) you can make a direct [`post`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) request to their GraphQL API. Have a look at [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/python) on how you can make it.

The screenshot shows how the request occurs during page refresh:

[image]

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/stackoverflow-scrape-inscription-website-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

html = requests.get("https://www.trulia.com/sold/32303_zip/6_srl/", timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

sold_homes = soup.select_one(".fdsGMZ").text
  
print(sold_homes)
```

Example output

```
809 sold homes on Trulia
```